# What's the result of multiple neurons using ReLU activation function?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, python, agi, relu

This question comes from a doubt that I recently had on an amazing book called "Neural Networks from Scratch With Python by Harrison Kinsley & Daniel Kukieła"
Let's suppose that I have two neurons in a hidden layer of my Neural Network, both using the ReLU activation function. The weight of the first connection between the input and the first neuron is -1.0 and let's add a bias of 0.5. The second neuron has a weight of -2.0 and a bias of 1.0 related to it. The input value would be 1.5, for instance. Why do we have a graph that seems like this:

[image: image from Neural Networks from Scratch With Python by Harrison Kinsley & Daniel Kukieła]

I mean, is the red line a new function that is changing through the chain of neurons? Would I be able to write this new equation? I really don't understand how neurons change the previous shape of the function, or how they fit it to desired output.

Comment: the function on the right is definitely some combination of the two neurons on the left  (for example a neuron in the next layer)